# Математический маятник с шаром

Tags: javascript, html, css

Итак, у нас есть математический маятник. Помогите реализовать, чтобы после запуска программы можно было в ручную (мышкой) поднять шар и отпустить для колебания 
P.s. Либо можно еще CSS или JavaScript

```html
<html>
<body>
<style>
 * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
 canvas {display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
</style>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" style="background: #eee"></canvas>
</body>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2")
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d")
var h = canvas.height = 500
var w = canvas.width = 600
var h2 = canvas2.height = 300
var w2 = canvas2.width = 800
ctx.translate(w/2,h/2)
ctx2.translate(0,h2/2)
ctx2.beginPath()
ctx2.moveTo(0,0)
 
var initPhi = Math.PI*0.2
var L = 200
var dt = 1/60
var g = 1500
var t = 0
 
bob = {
 phi: initPhi,
 v: 0,
 a: 0
}
function drawPendulum(){
 ctx.beginPath()
 ctx.arc(Math.sin(bob.phi)*L,Math.cos(bob.phi)*L,10,0,2*Math.PI)
 ctx.fill()
 ctx.moveTo(0,0)
 ctx.lineTo(Math.sin(bob.phi)*L,Math.cos(bob.phi)*L)
 ctx.stroke()
}
function update(){
 bob.a = -(g/L)*Math.sin(bob.phi)
 bob.v +=  bob.a*dt
 bob.phi += bob.v*dt
    t += dt
}
function drawGraph(){
 ctx2.lineTo(t*20,(bob.phi%Math.PI)*20 )
 ctx2.stroke()
}
function draw(){
 ctx.clearRect(-w/2,-h/2,w,h)
 drawPendulum()
 update()
    drawGraph()
 requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}
draw()
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Не совсем по теме, но вот реализация затухающего математического маятника: https://kagg.eu/christmas-balls-like-a-damped-pendulum/

Answer (score 4):

Все, на самом деле, достаточно просто. Нужно сделать несколько вещей:

- определить обработчик нажатия на левую кнопку мыши (ЛКМ)
- определить обработчик отжатия ЛКМ
- определить обработчик перемещения мыши

В обработчике нажатия ЛКМ нужно поменять режим (draggin <- true) и сохранить текущее положение центра канваса (относительно которого рисуется маятник) и угол направления от центра канваса на положение курсора мыши, а так же текущий угол поворота маятника.

В обработчике отжатия ЛКМ нужно поменять режим (draggin <- false) и обнулить текущую скорость и ускорение - чтобы не поломать физику процесса.

В обработчике перемещения мыши нужно понять в каком режиме мы сейчас находимся (если `draggin === true` - то нужно обрабатывать перемещение).

При обработке перемещения вычисляется новый угол направления на курсор и разница между текущим и начальным углами направления вычитается из сохраненного положения маятника.

Так же нужно не забыть запрещать пересчитывать механику при перемещении начальной точки.

Мой вариант кода с коментариями приведен ниже:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
var h = canvas.height = 500;
var w = canvas.width = 600;
var h2 = canvas2.height = 300;
var w2 = canvas2.width = 800;

var draggin = false; // В режиме перемещения  
var dragX = 0; // Центр канваса, относительно которого будем считать поворот
var dragY = 0;
var dragPhi = 0; // Угол маятника при нажатии
var dragKsy = 0; // Начальный угол при mousedown

ctx.translate(w / 2, h / 2);
ctx2.translate(0, h2 / 2);
ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.moveTo(0, 0);

var initPhi = Math.PI * 0.2;
var L = 200;
var dt = 1 / 60;
var g = 1500;
var t = 0;

bob = {
  phi: initPhi,
  v: 0,
  a: 0
};

//getPos - определение позиции относительно центра элемента
function getPos(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: rect.left + rect.width / 2.0,
    y: rect.top + rect.height / 2.0
  };
}

// Определяем угол поворота относительно центра канваса
function calcKsy(evt) {
  var deltaX = evt.clientX - dragX;
  var deltaY = evt.clientY - dragY;
  var Ksy = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
  return Ksy;
}

// Обрабатываем событие нажатия на левую кнопку мыши
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(evt) {
  var gpc = getPos(canvas);
  dragX = gpc.x;
  dragY = gpc.y;
  draggin = true;
  dragPhi = bob.phi;
  dragKsy = calcKsy(evt);
});

// Поворачиваем маятник на угол между начальным углом при mousedown
// и текущим после перемещения курсора
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
  if(draggin){
     var Ksy = calcKsy(evt);
     bob.phi = dragPhi - Ksy + dragKsy;
  }
});

// Обрабатываем событие отжатия левой кнопки мыши
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(evt) {
  draggin = false;
  bob.v = 0;
  bob.a = 0;
});

function drawPendulum() {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.arc(Math.sin(bob.phi) * L, Math.cos(bob.phi) * L, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
  ctx.fill()
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0)
  ctx.lineTo(Math.sin(bob.phi) * L, Math.cos(bob.phi) * L)
  ctx.stroke()
}

function update() {
  bob.a = -(g / L) * Math.sin(bob.phi)
  bob.v += bob.a * dt
  bob.phi += bob.v * dt
  t += dt
}

function drawGraph() {
  ctx2.lineTo(t * 20, (bob.phi % Math.PI) * 20)
  ctx2.stroke()
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(-w / 2, -h / 2, w, h)
  drawPendulum()
  // Если мы не в режиме перетаскивания, то качаем маятник
  if (draggin === false) {
    update()
  }
  drawGraph()
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}

draw()
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: move;
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" style="background: #eee"></canvas>
```